# Как работать с готовой нейронной сетью на сервере?

Tags: веб-программирование, нейронные-сети, backend

Доброго времени суток.

Хочу создать веб сайт на react с функционалом нейросети, с клиентом проблем нет.

Нужно написать API (планирую на nest.js) для модели, которая сохранена в файле формата .pt (клиент будет передавать запрос на бэк, бэк прогоняет данные через модель и возвращает клиенту результат). Существуют ли какие-то библиотеки на node для работы с такими моделями?

Или, если у Вас был опыт работы с подобного рода приложениями, поделитесь, пожалуйста, идеями для реализации.